Why submitting form programmatically using React-hook-form and useActionState, always got error `A React form was unexpectedly submitted`
I just followed a youtube tutorial about using server action with useFormState. When I following the video, There is an error fro react saying to use useActionState insted of useFormState. So I followed it up. Here is my current implementation
// actions.ts
"use server";

export const createItem = async (
  prevState: FormState,
  data: FormData
): Promise<FormState> => {
  const formData = Object.fromEntries(data.entries());
  const parsed = ConfigSchema.safeParse(formData);

  if (!parsed.success) {
    return {
      ...prevState,
      message: "failed",
      success: false,
    };
  }

  return {
    image: "https://picsum.photos/200/200",
    message: "success",
    success: true,
  };
};

// components.tsx

export const Step3 = () => {
  const step3 = useOrderStore((state) => state.step3);
  const formRef = React.useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null);
  const [state, formAction, isPending] = React.useActionState(createItem, {
    message: "",
    image: "",
    success: false,
  });

  console.log({ state, isPending });

  const configForm = useForm<IItemConfig>({
    resolver: zodResolver(ConfigSchema),
    defaultValues: step3,
  });

  return (
    <Card>
      <CardContent className="flex gap-8 lg:flex-row flex-col">
        <Form {...configForm}>
          <form
            className="order-3 lg:order-1"
            action={formAction}
            ref={formRef}
            onSubmit={configForm.handleSubmit(() => formRef.current?.submit())}
          >
            <div className="space-y-4 w-full">
              <FormField
                control={configForm.control}
                name="shape"
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <FormItem>
                    <FormLabel>Bentuk Dasar</FormLabel>
                    <Select
                      {...field}
                      defaultValue={field.value}
                      onValueChange={field.onChange}
                    >
                      <SelectTrigger data-testid="font-family-select">
                        <SelectValue />
                      </SelectTrigger>
                      <SelectContent>
                        {SHAPE_OPTIONS.map((shape) => (
                          <SelectItem key={shape.value} value={shape.value}>
                            {shape.label}
                          </SelectItem>
                        ))}
                      </SelectContent>
                    </Select>
                    <FormMessage />
                  </FormItem>
                )}
              />

              <Button type="submit" className="w-full">
                Generate
              </Button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </Form>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
};

Whenever I tried to submit, I will got error
Uncaught Error: A React form was unexpectedly submitted. If you called form.submit() manually, consider using form.requestSubmit() instead. If you're trying to use event.stopPropagation() in a submit event handler, consider also calling event.preventDefault().

I've tried to change using requestSubmit() but the form not submitted although the error is gone. Can someone help me pointed out the problem? thanks
I've tried to change using requestSubmit() but the form not submitted although the error is gone. Can someone help me pointed out the problem? thanks

I am getting the same error as well; looks like with the new useActionState, we cannot use both form action and onSubmit.
I may be wrong, but so far I couldn't find a way to use both
